# How to find the best value of k For the k-NN?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification, data-science, knn

I have 4 different datasets and Each dataset contains two-dimensional samples that belong to one of the two classes: 1 or 2. The class labels (1 or 2) for each sample are located in the last column. The first and second columns contain the coordinates of the 2D points that represent the samples. My task is,

1. For the k-NN find the best value of k, and compare it with those of 1-NN using Scikit

I am new to machine learning and python. please let me know how to find the best k and based on which measure we have to choose best k.

Answer (score 1):

Note, that `k` in your case is a [hyperparameter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperparameter_(machine_learning)). To tune it, you need to split your data set into train and test buckets and classify each element of test multiple times for a range of values k, for example from 1 to 20. Calculate accuracy (or precision/recall) in every case.

Then plot accuracy values for every k and select small enough k which gives you a "good" accuracy. Usually, people look at the slope of the chart and select smallest `k`, such as previous value `k-1` significantly decreases accuracy.

Note, that the value `k` would highly depend on your data. For example, in the chart below (Credit: https://kevinzakka.github.io/2016/07/13/k-nearest-neighbor/) a good choice of `k` would be 8, as it results to the lowest misclassification error.

[image]

This link might be helpful as well: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-nearest_neighbors_algorithm#Parameter_selection

Comment: Thanks for your response.                                                                                       I have another doubt... I find the k value but I got the same accuracy for more than one k . So in this condition which k should i select? min k value or max k value?

Comment: In general, min k is better, as your system needs less information to produce the same result. You could also try to run your experiment multiple times and average accuracy for different k across experiments. It might result in better robustness of the algorithm.